# Powershell unrar with wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to extract about 40 folders with each containing a rar, but I never have done in it powershell. 
In bash you can use `*/*.rar` to extract them using a wildcard, but how do I this in powershell ? I tried something along

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Unrar\UnRAR.exe' x  .\*\*.rar
```

But it errors:

```
UNRAR 4.10 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal

Cannot read contents of .\*\*.rar
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
$parent = 'c:\myrar_files'

$files = @()

Get-ChildItem $parent -Recurse -Filter "*.rar" | % {

    # Recurse through all subfolders looking for .rar files only.

    $files = $files + $_.FullName
}

foreach ($f in $files) {

    # UnRAR the files. -y responds Yes to any queries UnRAR may have.

   C:\scripts\WinRAR\unrar x -y $f
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Test this first because I don't have anything to test it on**:

```
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.rar | %{"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unrar\UnRAR.exe" x $_.fullpath}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the x will cause it to extract to the current directory or the directory of the rar file so you may have to add a cd to the commands.

```
get-childitem -recurse -filter *.rar | %{cd $_.directory; "C:\Program Files (x86)\Unrar\UnRAR.exe" x $_.name}
```

Comment: The first one gives me: 
>>
                     The second one gives me: http://pastebin.com/KX7ifaaZ

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Ehm The standard one in windows 7 :/

Comment: Try the first one again, I had an unterminated quote.

Comment: Unexpected token 'x' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:84
+ get-childitem -recurse -filter *.rar | %{"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unrar\UnRAR.exe" x <<<<  $_.fullpath}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (x:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken